# $q.all create dynamic promises with a loop in angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angular-promise

I want to make a loop which englobe my second promise so every time it pass in my loop a new promise is create:

```
var promise1 =   $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations/"+id+"/users.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}

});

var promise2 = promise1.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for(i = 0; i < data.data.users.length; i++){
            console.log(data.data.users.length);
        var userid = data.data.users[i].id;
            console.log(userid);

       return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/"+userid+"/tickets/requested.json",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}

        })
    }
});

$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(data){
    console.log(data[0].data.users, data[1]);
});
```

In this code, the loop is not working because `promise2` only return one result.

Can you help me pls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of your code more as a chain of events that you want to fire off. Forget synchronous - forget the line by line perspective.

In this case, we fire off the first http request. Then, in respone to the request, we fire off a bunch of userid http requests, and build up an array list of the returned promises.

Then using $q.all, we respond collectivley to all those promises, and do a console log.

```
var promise1 =   $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations/"+id+"/users.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',   'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}

});

promise1.then(function(data) {
    var allQ = [];
    var allData = [];
    console.log(data);
    for(i = 0; i < data.data.users.length; i++){
            console.log(data.data.users.length);
        var userid = data.data.users[i].id;
            console.log(userid);

       allQ.push( $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/"+userid+"/tickets/requested.json",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}

        }).then( function(data){ allData.push( data)} ) );
    }
    $q.all(allQ).then(function(data){
        //You will probably want to iterate allData
        console.log( allData);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it is very helpfull, however, i did not get my data from `promise1` wich  is logical because  'allQ' is in parameter of my function result.

Comment: Oh crikey. Yes the returned data, sorry i missed that. Let me update.

Comment: Because after i need to wrap all data from every promise in the same array and it will not be easy :p